# How to count rows in MySQL using an IF statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relatively simple question but I'm stuck with writing a proper SQL query to display the results that I need. I have a table which stores results from matches with columns indicating the IDs of the players that took part in the match, the winner and another boolean column which let's say indicates whether I want to include that match in the result or not. So the columns are:

```
player1_id | player2_id | winner_id | use
```

So `winner_id` is the value from one of the first two columns depending on which player won. If I want to count how many times a certain player won a game just using the rows where the `use` flag is up, I can easily do so with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, winner_id
FROM table 
WHERE use = 1
GROUP BY winner_id
ORDER BY total DESC
```

However, I also want to do the same count but for the players that lost their matches. In other words, I want to group not by the `winner_id` but by the loser id, which would be the value of either `player1_id` or `player2_id` depending on which one of them is different from the `winner_id`. Any clues on how to do that with a simple query that works?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Terrible table design - 1st col winner, 2nd col opponent.

Comment: Not arguing that it is good table design but some matches are set between two players without knowing in advance who is going to win.

Comment: Separate table for schedule; then a table for results. Review data normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this to count the loosers:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    IF(player1_id = winner_id, player2_id, player1_id) AS looser_id
FROM table
WHERE use = 1
GROUP BY looser_id
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Good answer, but why do you recommend not using `COUNT(*)`? This is the natural way to count records. You'd count a column instead only when you want NULL detection (e.g. in an outer join).

Comment: You are right Thorsten... thanks for the correction. To count a specific column is not relevant in this case. I will correct my answer.